# Fabric: Set "bubble size" (rate limit) for just a single function (not task)

Tags: python, multithreading, fabric

Suppose I have the following Fabric fabfile:

```
import time

def part1():
    print 'doing part 1'
    time.sleep(1)

def part2():
    print 'doing part 2'
    time.sleep(10)

def bothparts():
    part1()
    part2()
```

I would like to be able to run both `fab -H a,b,c,d bothparts` (serially) and `fab -P -H a,b,c,d bothparts` (in parallel), with the natural semantics. Serial execution should take 44 seconds; parallel execution should take 11 seconds.

**However, here's the wrinkle.** In my real code, `part1` makes a query to a remote server that rate-limits incoming queries (to, let's say, two at a time). So `fab -P -H a,b,c,d bothparts` runs to completion on hosts `a` and `b`, but bombs out on `c` and `d`.

I'm looking for a way to "rate-limit" the number of concurrent calls to `part1`.

I know about ["bubble size"](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/parallel.html#bubble-size), but I cannot accept `fab -P -z 2 -H a,b,c,d bothparts` as an answer, because that will take 22 seconds to complete. I'm looking for a way to implement the answer that takes only 12 seconds (1 second to do `part1` for `a,b`, 1 second to do `part1` for `c,d` while `a,b` go on to begin `part2`, 9 seconds where all four tasks are running in parallel, and finally 1 second while `c,d` finish up `part2`).

I wasted a lot of time trying to make it work with a "@synchronized" decorator (using a `threading.Semaphore`, similar to [this blog post](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/the-missing-synchronized-decorator.html)), but when that didn't work, I did some more research and realized that Fabric uses *multiple processes* for its parallelism! I need those multiple *processes* to talk to each other, if I want to solve the problem.

---

I also can't accept the manual solution `fab -P -z 2 -H a,b,c,d part1 && fab -P -H a,b,c,d part2`; basically I'm looking for the simplest possible Fabric code that could wrap that up into a simple `bothparts` task. I suspect there's a solution involving `execute` inside `bothparts`, but my ***ideal*** solution would be a local change to the innards of `part1` (because I don't want to have to rewrite all the callers of `part1` just because of this implementation detail).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "technically correct" solution that isn't very satisfying because it's not composable:

```
import time
from fabric.decorators import parallel, runs_once

@parallel(pool_size=2)
def part1():
    print 'doing part 1'
    time.sleep(1)

@parallel
def part2():
    print 'doing part 2'
    time.sleep(10)

@runs_once
def bothparts():
    execute(part1)
    execute(part2)

$ fab -H a,b,c,d bothparts
```

The philosophical problem with this solution is that it doesn't seem to compose well; it's extremely unclear to me how to invoke `part1` or `part2` from another task, or how to invoke `bothparts` from another task.

Also, this `bothparts` supertask needs to know about the weird behavior of its subtasks. Notice that if you remove the `@runs_once` decoration on `bothparts`, you end up running `part1` four times *per machine*, and then running `part2` four times *per machine*, which is incorrect.